# How to make the length of two vectors equal in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, noise-reduction

I am trying to remove the noise from signals and shown below is the code I am using. `your text`

```
Fs = 100000000;
Ts=1/Fs;
dt= 0:Ts:0.0003;    % time vector
f = 50e03;         % frequency of the signal

x = Signal{1,2};

% Define the filter parameters
Fc = 50e03;              % cutoff frequency of the filter

y = highpass(x, Fc, Fs);

% Plot the original and filtered signals
plot(dt,x,'b',dt,y,'r');
```

I am trying to remove the noise from an ultrasonic signal. I am getting an error that it is unable to plot because the vectors are not of the same length. How should I fix this?

Comment: could you please share the error log in its completeness?

Comment: You need to create you time vector `dt` to be of the same length as `x`. Something like `dt = (0:numel(x)-1) * Ts`.